# React Native run Android error (at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11))

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I do react-native run-android it throws this error:

```
    > Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
24 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 22 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
> Could not read path 'C:\Users\Maxson52\Documents\Coding-Projects\Schoolio\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJniLibs\debug\0\lib\armeabi-v7a'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
> Could not read path 'C:\Users\Maxson52\Documents\Coding-Projects\Schoolio\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJniLibs\debug\0\lib\armeabi-v7a'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Maxson52\Documents\Coding-Projects\Schoolio\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\Maxson52\Documents\Coding-Projects\Schoolio\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
    at C:\Users\Maxson52\Documents\Coding-Projects\Schoolio\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Maxson52\Documents\Coding-Projects\Schoolio\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:7)
```

I've created a brand new project with react-native init and tried to run it but I get the same error.

I've tried to delete the `.gradle/caches` folder from both the project (which does nothing) and the from `Users/Maxson52/.gradle/caches` but neither fixes the problem.

I don't use Expo as I prefer create-react-native-app but not a single project of mine (that I've tried) works anymore. I don't believe I've installed or removed anything important but tips for what to try are appreciated.

I'm not sure why nothing is running when I try and run my project, my phone is plugged in and ready.

Edited with the entire error. Noticed something about deprecated gradle even though it is a fresh made react native project, is that the problem and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Above that stacktrace there may be something more useful, please include the full error starting from the text `* What went wrong`

Comment: Updated with the entire error from start to finish.